# Powershell rename based on a pattern

Tags: powershell

I have the below file structure

```
File.Name.S01.E01.Mp4
File.Name.S11.E01.Mp4
File.Name.S21.E01.Mp4
```

I have a script to remove all of the . and results in the below.

```
FileNameS01E01.Mp4
FileNameS11E01.Mp4
FileNameS21E01.Mp4
```

What I am hoping for is actually the below format

```
FileName S01E01.Mp4
FileName S11E01.Mp4
FileName S21E01.Mp4
```

Is there any way to match the pattern of "if there is a S"number"E"Number" then put a space before the S?

My current code is as follows:

```
cd 'C:\Users\ME\Desktop\HERE'
dir -recurse | where {-Not $_.PsIscontainer -AND $_.name -match "."} | 
foreach {
$New=$_.BaseName.Replace(".","")+$_.Extension
Rename-Item -path $_.Fullname -newname $New -passthru
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming consistency in your filenames:

```
$New = $_.Replace(".S"," S").Replace(".E","E").Replace(".","")
```

---

**Example**

```
PS C:> $basename = "File.Name.S01.E01"
PS C:> $basename.Replace(".S"," S").Replace(".E","E").Replace(".","")
FileName S01E01
```

Comment: Hello, yes everything works well once I noticed it was sensitive to the S and or E being caps. thanks so much!!